# Trying to get pureSlider to work with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using pureSlider and I have a bootstrap navbar that requires jquery to collapse and toggle the menus on smaller devices/screens. Is there a way to get both the pureSlider and jquery elements to work on my page?

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pureSlider.js"></script>


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

      <style>

          html {
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #4be1f0;
          }


          body {
                font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
                position: relative;
                background-color: #4be1f0;

          }

          #container {
              width: 1200px;
              height: auto;
              margin: 100px auto;
          }


      </style>
  </head>

    <body>

        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" id="mynavBar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#a">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#promise">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="banner2">
                <div class="stage">
                    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('images/banner.jpg')"><span/>RESPONSIVE</span></div>
                    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('assets/img/img2.jpg')"><span/>PERSONALIZED</span></div>
                    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('assets/img/img3.jpg')"><span/>PROFESSIONAL</span></div>
                    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('assets/img/img4.jpg')"><span/>OPTIMIZED</span></div>
    <!--                <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('assets/img/poppies.jpg')"><span>Poppies on fifth slide</span></div>-->
                    <div class="next">&rtrif;</div>
                    <div class="prev">&ltrif;</div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>







        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<!--    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
         $('.stage').pureSlider({ 
        slideNode: '.slide'
        });
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to comment out the jquery.min.js script at the bottom in order to get the slider to work but doing so wont allow my bootstrap navbar to collapse or toggle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but looking at the code:

- you don't strictly need jBone for pureSlider to work, infact, loading jBone with jQuery will cause a conflict. pureSlider will work with any jQuery-compatible library as long as you load it after that library.
- since 0.8.0 pureSlider doesn't depend on jQuery-like libraries anymore, so it doesn't matter when you load it, unless you want to use it in the jQuery-like fashion: `$('collection').pureSlider();`, in which case it needs to be loaded after jQuery, so it can register as its plugin.